# How to pass environment variables to postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose

```
  database:
   container_name: k4fntr_database
   build: ./docker/postgres
   restart: always
   environment:
     ENV: ${APP_ENV}
     TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
     POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
     POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
   ports:
    - "15432:5432"
   volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
   networks:
    - backend-network
```

I want to create 2 additional databases after container build but only if it is a local development.

For it I`ve created a folder docker-entrypoint-initdb.d which is contains a script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

if [ "$ENV" == 'local' ]; then
     (
      echo "CREATE DATABASE $TESTING_DB OWNER $POSTGRES_USER;"
     ) | (export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD && psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U $POSTGRES_USER)
fi
```

I also have a dockerfile where I copy this folder to container

```
FROM postgres:10.5-alpine
COPY /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

but problem is that this file was copied without variables values.

How can I pass those variables?

Comment: What does "Copied without variable values" mean... The script is going to pick up the environment variable you are setting `$ENV` only when the script runs inside the container. After launching the container, get a shell into the container and type `echo $ENV` that should pick up whatever value you set in `$APP_ENV`.

Comment: Hmmm...it`s really true. I`ve run this script via sh and my database was created. But why this script wasn`t started by container? From documentation 

If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary). After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user and database, it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts

Comment: There's a check in the [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh): `if [ -z "$DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS" ]; then` with comment *"only run initialization on an empty data directory"*. I wonder if that's fouling things up here. I don't see anything in your docker-compose or DOCKERFILE that suggests that there is already a database set up though (like through a volume mount...)

Comment: maybee this line?     volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw